# Print variable from right to left in java

Tags: java, println

I want to print variable from right. This is my code to show '#' symbol:

```
static void printNumberSignVertical(int n, boolean newLine){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.print('#');
    }
    if(newLine){
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

and then this is my output :

[image]

I want to print symbol '#' from the right. How can i make that symbol printed from right to left?

this is my representation how the print order is desired :

[image]

it starts from 1st one.

Comment: What do you mean right-to-left? You want it to print from the right side of the screen instead?

Comment: yes, i want to print symbol '#' from the right side first @Zephyr

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/textlayoutbidirectionaltext.html

Comment: or search for java rtl

Comment: @ScaryWombat - It looks like the OP is using the console. Would the AWT article apply? (I'm not familiar with AWT, but I believe it is all GUI-based, no?)

Comment: @dazzle - I'm not sure that can be done with `System.out` as the text direction depends on the OS and console implementation. You might need to do some calculations to determine the width of the display and go from there.

Comment: @dazzle your requirement is not clear enough. Could you please add your current and expected outcome examples.

Comment: i have edited my question and give an example about my representation ouput @VicJordan

Comment: @dazzle sadly I can not see images you have posted. Could you please post links from other site or instead of image provide textual information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the terminal is exactly 80 characters wide, you *could* use formatted io to indent the `String` (`#`) (and a newline). Like,

```
System.out.printf("%80s%n", "#");
```

This still has to draw left to right, but it will align as I think you wanted.

Comment: thankyou, but what i want is how to print from the right side first

Comment: @dazzle Was there something in my answer that made you think I did not understand that from your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 79; i > -1; i--){
if(i>=n){
System.out.print(" ");
}else{
System.out.print('#');
     }


}
```

[image: Example for n=4]

Example for n=4

Comment: it still print from the left side